# track all the versions of stored procedure which is modified multiple times

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

If a stored procedure is modified 10 times , i want to log or track it in a table in a column in 10 rows from initial stored procedure to the latest  that is 10 different versions of the same stored procedure , could any one suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which version of SQL server you're using, but have you looked at [DDL triggers?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190989(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: In which case, DDL triggers are available to you - I have updated the documentation link to the 2005 version.

Comment: DDL Triggers are definitely a good idea.  I blogged about using DDL triggers to propogate stored procedure changes in the following article - you can easily adapt the code to your logging: http://thehobt.blogspot.com/2009/03/synchronizing-changes-to-stored.html

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm not directly answering your question, but did you consider using a source control tool for it? Like svn, source safe, ...

Comment: svn is there, but still i need to store in a database the different versions of a single stored procedure, it should not be a manually process ,
that is if 10 service packs are applied on production database for same stored procedures that is to say 10 different versions of stored procedures are applied.
i want to track all these 10 versions in table in the database from the 1st version to 10 th version.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using dot net it will be a good idea to create a Database project where you can store the SP as well as scripts for all other objects and use some source control where you will be able to maintain version history.